# gevent.hub.LoopExit: This operation would block forever

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, gevent, greenlets

Trying to use select.select in Python to monitor something under /proc/. Initially, it threw

```
   r, w, x = select.select([],[],[fd])
   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Since we are using gevents, used this to get rid of the above error:

```
from gevent import monkey, select
monkey.patch_all()
```

Now, I am facing another error, I don't seem to use anything which gevent would not like(like we should use gevent.sleep instead of sleep). This is the code:

```
from gevent import monkey, select
monkey.patch_all()

file_dp = open("/proc/<>")

while True:
    r, w, x = select.select([],[],[fd])
    file_dp.seek(0)
    print(file_dp.read())
```

Here is the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 8, in <module>
    read, write, exc = select.select([],[],[fd])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.9/site-packages/gevent/select.py", line 69, in select
    result.event.wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.9/site-packages/gevent/event.py", line 77, in wait
    result = self.hub.switch()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.9/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 331, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
gevent.hub.LoopExit: This operation would block forever
```

Comment: Not sure if gevent supports xlist in select.select([],[],[fd])

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/c780319e87025130a06f7d2eb9e33ff6d25361dd/src/gevent/select.py#L142), xlist is not supported.